# Insert one ad every XX posts with php module

Tags: php, module, include

Sorry it's a silly question I'm blocked with.

I need to insert the ad and keep inserting posts, not just replace the post by the ad that is what I have with this code:

```
$counter = 0;
foreach($tweets as $tweet) { 
if(++$counter % 4 === 0) { 
 include './advertisment/advertisment.php';
    }
```

So as follows:

```
0 0
1 0
2 0
3 1

4 0
5 0
6 0
7 2
```

I've also tried adding on advertisment.php a  return if(++$counter % 4 === 0) but doesn't seems to work as needed.

Thanks

Comment: Your current code does not replace anything. And there is no output so where do the `0` and `1` come from? Please show some more code so we can see what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

Given a basic file called `ad.php` within the same directory as the test script

```
<?php
    #ad.php
    printf('<div class="advert" style="color:red">Hello World, Im an advert...%s</div>',uniqid());
?>
```

And the test script

```
$tweets=range(100,200);  # To emulate the tweets that you have
$interval=3; # how often to insert an ad

foreach( $tweets as $index => $value ){
    # Every X tweets (iterations through array/loop include the Advert
    if( $index > 0 && $index % $interval===0 )require 'ad.php';

    # For every iteration through the loop print out the tweet or whatever
    printf('<div class="tweet" style="color:blue">[ Index:%d - Value:%d ]Tweet, tweet, tweet!</div>',$index,$value);
}
```

This yields output like this:

[image]

as text:

```
[ Index:0 - Value:100 ]Tweet, tweet, tweet!
[ Index:1 - Value:101 ]Tweet, tweet, tweet!
[ Index:2 - Value:102 ]Tweet, tweet, tweet!
Hello World, Im an advert...63a6bdbeecd05
[ Index:3 - Value:103 ]Tweet, tweet, tweet!
[ Index:4 - Value:104 ]Tweet, tweet, tweet!
[ Index:5 - Value:105 ]Tweet, tweet, tweet!
Hello World, Im an advert...63a6bdbeee08d
[ Index:6 - Value:106 ]Tweet, tweet, tweet!
[ Index:7 - Value:107 ]Tweet, tweet, tweet!
[ Index:8 - Value:108 ]Tweet, tweet, tweet!
Hello World, Im an advert...63a6bdbeef415
```

I hope this helps solve your issue.